# Python Mechanize : Page not loading fully

Tags: python, facebook, mechanize

The code snippet i am using ::

```
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

response = br.open('http://www.facebook.com')
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['email'] = USERNAME
br['pass'] = PASSWORD
response2 = br.submit()

assert br.viewing_html()
time.sleep(50) 


for form in br.forms():
    print form
```

Well i tried writing out response2.read() to file to see what was happening . Only the top navigation bar has loaded . The intention of having time.sleep(50) was to provide time for page load but guess that doesnt work .

What is the right way to do this ?

Comment: I know this can done using fb api but i wanted to try using mechanize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're passing the correct login?

I've run your code with my login and it works fine for me.

The only thing I'll add is that you don't need the `time.sleep(50)` in there—Mechanize blocks until it receives all the content.

**Make your question more useful by giving us your *complete* code sample *and* the output (including** `print response2`**).**

Comment: So once it logs in - note fb loads its content using ajax - mechanize isnt able to view the share box or for that matter any other content other than top navigation bar

Comment: *Facebook loads its content using Ajax* — if you have JavaScript on, yes. We don't. Have you tried changing your UA? Telling Facebook that you're Firefox will make it think you're Firefox. Change it to something non-browser

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be scraping www.facebook.com.

The right way to get what you are after is to use Facebook Platform as @infrared notes.

Comment: Well this question is general to all sites using ajax and about using mechanize . I have used fb api but just trying if its possible .

Comment: Mechanize doesn't have a JavaScript interpreter, ergo it won't run JS or Ajax